# How to configure Multiple .wsdl in CXF Maven Plugin

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

In the following example i am able to configure WSDL.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <!-- for myService1.wsdl -->
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/myService1.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <!-- for myService2.wsdl -->
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/myService2.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    . . .
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But my question is what if i have 100  and more WSDL then i need to add it 100 and more times.

Is there any generic way to avoid this writtig in multiple times in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

The `<wsdlRoot>` element can be specified for using multiple wsdls without needing to explicitly reference them.

`<includes>` can be used to further select the wsdls under `<wsdlRoot>`

```
<configuration>
    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
    <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
     <includes>
          <include>*Service.wsdl</include>
     </includes>                
</configuration>
```

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxf-codegen-plugin(WSDLtoJava)-Example5:UsingwsdlRootwithincludes/excludespatterns